# Using awk or sed to remove the first character fom the fourt and fifth column in a .csv

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a .csv file with the following values:

```
N0012,17/01/20,13:31:42,N52:01:58,E004:19:00
```

I need to remove the N and E from the fourth and fifth column.
So the output is:

```
N0012,17/01/20,13:31:42,52:01:58,004:19:00
```

I did try using

```
awk '{gsub(/\N|\;/,$4)}1' file
```

but it also removes the fist N from the first column.

So I need some assistance with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can there be any other letter or just `N` and `E`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^N/,"",$4);sub(/^E/,"",$5)} 1' Input_file
```

In case OP wants to substitute any letter (not only N or E) then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^[[:alpha:]]/,"",$4);sub(/^[[:alpha:]]/,"",$5)} 1' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^./,"",$4);sub(/^./,"",$5)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{               ##Starting BEGIN section of this awk program from here.
  FS=OFS=","         ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma here.
}
{
  sub(/^N/,"",$4)    ##Using substitute function of awk to substitute starting N in column 4th here.
  sub(/^E/,"",$5)    ##Using substitute function of awk to substitute starting N in column 5th here.
}
1                    ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){3})N/\1/;s/^(([^,]*,){4})E/\1/' file
```

If the first three fields are followed by an `N` replace the match by the first three fields.

If the first four fields are followed by an `E` replace the match by the first four fields.

Answer (score 0):

Given your posted sample input this is all you need:

```
$ sed 's/,[NE]/,/g' file
N0012,17/01/20,13:31:42,52:01:58,004:19:00
```

or if you prefer awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,[NE]/,",")}1' file
N0012,17/01/20,13:31:42,52:01:58,004:19:00
```